# How to show last 13 months in X axis based on single slicer selection?

Tags: data-visualization, powerbi

**EDIT:** As this is an old question, the intended solution is supported by the relative date slicer in Power BI as seen [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/power-bi/visuals/desktop-slicer-filter-date-range).

I am building a rolling 13 month net revenue chart and I've came across a requirement to show the last 13 month in x axis based in what month (YYYYMM) the user selected in a YYYYMM slicer.

The chart below is the one I want:

[image]

In order to get the intended behaviour, currently I need to select each one of the 13 month in YYYYMM slicer:

[image]

Any ideas on how I can get this to work in Power BI so that the user just have to select the base month?

Thanks in advance,
Cristhian.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a table `data(date, value)`.

Add a table `datefilter(date)` with dates you want to select. Add a slicer by this date.

Add a calculated column to `data` : `date2 = DATEADD('data'[date].[Date],13,MONTH)`

Add this measure:

```
current = IF(AND(
  MAX('data'[date]) < MAX('datefilter'[date]),
  MAX('data'[date2]) > MAX('datefilter'[date])),1,0)
```

filter your visualisation by `current is 1`.

[image]